# How to return if optional is present and continue if not

Tags: java, java-8

I have a optional method which returns `Cat` object (which is a optional). From the place I call It i would like to handle it in a way `if cat is present then return otherwise continue`

```
Opitional<Cat> option = isCatFound();
if (option.isPresent()) {
return option.get();
}
//DO STUFF HERE IF NO CAT FOUND
```

The above code is what I have now. I like to use something better than that, a single line solution.

Is there such possibility ? or correct way to use Optional ?

Comment: will this help       "expression?condition1:condition2"

Comment: otherwise continue with what?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since your method has to return a value of that type at the end, you could use

```
Optional<Cat> option = isCatFound();
return option.orElseGet(() -> {
  // DO STUFF HERE IF NO CAT FOUND
  // WHICH WILL EVENTUALLY RETURN A VALUE
};
```

If your “stuff if no cat found” fits into a single line, it might be an option.
Otherwise I don’t see any advantage over your original code. Especially as it has the disadvantage that the alternative code path can’t throw checked exceptions any more.

Answer (score 10):

The `Optional` class provides a method for exactly that purpose: [`orElseGet(Supplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-). So, with some little helper method you can do this:

```
Optional<Cat> option = isCatFound();
return option.orElseGet(this::noCatFound);

private Cat noCatFound() {
    // do whatever is appropriate here
    return null;
}
```

Of course, you could move the helper method's body into a lambda exprssion that feeds the `orElseGet` method.

Answer (score 3):

First, I'd change the name of `isCatFound()`. The good pattern is to use function's name that can be answered with "yes" or "no" only for functions returning `boolean`. For instance, your `isCatFound` method should return `true` or `false` which would imply that cat is found or not. If it returns `Optional<Cat>` I'd name it just `getCat()`.

Then, you could take advantage of `orElseGet(Supplier<? extends T>)` member of `Optional`. It returns value if it's present or invokes `Supplier` otherwise. For your example it could look like this:

```
return getCat().orElseGet(() -> {
    //Whatever you want to do
    //return result
});
```

Notice that in the above example it's really easy to read'n'understand the code. It tells you exactly what it does: `Get cat or get whatever lambda returns otherwise`.

If you are not familiar with Lambdas, take a look at this article: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html